# Как программно задать параметры wcf-сервиса

Tags: c#, wcf

Доброго времени суток!
Я пытаюсь программно задать настройки точек подключения для config файла wcf-сервиса, пробовал использовать класс channelFactory, но с помощью данного класса получилось, только указать откуда брать данные уже не посредственно, во время выполнения методов сервиса, а как изменить настройки во время старта сервиса не могу сообразить.

Comment: @sp7, зачем Вам код, если вы работали с сервисами, то вы должны представлять структуру сервисов и мне нужен, не кусок кода, а совет по поводу реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете посмотреть это в официальной документации, или вот: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-service-endpoint-in-code

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.